# Saving date into database and get it with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, save

Like the title says, how can I use this date function to save it as a string or so I can get that later out of the database?

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$newsTitel   = $_POST['title'];
$submitDate  = date('Y-m-d g:i:s A');
$newsContent = $_POST['newstext'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Nieuwstitel, Nieuwsbericht, Postdatum) 
     VALUES('$newsTitel', '$newsContent', '$submitDate' ) ");
echo "Het bericht is successvol geplaatst!";
echo date('Y-m-d g:i:s A');
```

This displays the news like the date: 2012 only when it has to be the full lenght:

```
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");   
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY newsid DESC");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo "<table class='newsList'>";

    echo "<tr><div id='nav'><th align='left'>".$row['Nieuwstitel']."</th>
              <th class='right'>".$row['Postdatum']."</div></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".$row['Nieuwsbericht']."<br/></td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
  if ($count == 0){
     echo "<center><p>No news at the moment!</p><p>&nbsp;</p></center>";
  }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Save your dates as datetime or timestamp (in MySQL for example) and then when you use/display them you format it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: That is pretty easy to google sir.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using string dates, why don't you use the MySQL function and when you output this value later, you can simply format it. use Now() function like this;

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Nieuwstitel, Nieuwsbericht, Postdatum)       
VALUES('$newsTitel', '$newsContent', NOW()) ");
```

This will give you the current datetime.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with anyone who says to save your dates in the database as unix timestamp (as a lot of PHP programmers seem to want to do out of laziness).  This makes the data in your table harder to read in a human readable form, and harder to query using MySQL's date/time functions.

If you are just trying to set the current timestamp at the time of the query, I would actually suggest using mysql's NOW() function in your insert query like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Nieuwstitel, Nieuwsbericht, Postdatum) VALUES('$newsTitel', '$newsContent', NOW() ) ");
```

This removes the need for you to do any time formulations in PHP.

Comment: Well this doesn't load it like an actual date for me on the webpage. Still says 2012

Comment: It might have to do with your HTML and CSS.  Your <th> tag where you are outputing the date is not properly closed for example.  Can you verify the value in the page source is just '2012'?  Can you verify you are actually using a datetime field in the database for PostDatum?